# Upgrade angular-ui-router 1.X: Resolve data not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've upgraded my version of Angular to 1.7.8 and also upgraded angular-ui-router to  1.0.22.

After upgrade my resolved data from the router configuration isn't working (anymore).

Route configuration:

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
views: {
    '@' : {
        templateUrl: CONFIG.BasePath + '/article/views/layout.html'
    },
    'article@app': {
        templateUrl: CONFIG.BasePath + '/article/views/index.html',
        controller: 'ArticleController',
        resolve : {
            settings: function() {
                return {
                    someValue: ''
                };
            },
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                // other code
            }]
        }
    }
}})
```

Controller:

```
function MapController ($scope, settings) {
    console.log(settings);
}

MapController.$inject = [
    '$scope',
    'settings'
];
```

When I try to access it from the resolves object, it works, but this is not the way to go imho...

```
function MapController ($scope) {
    console.log($scope.myResolves.$state$.views['article@app'].resolve.settings());
}

MapController.$inject = [
    '$scope'
]
```

Answer (score 3):

ui-router 1.0 does not support resolve into views:

> We no longer process resolve blocks that are declared inside a views.

you need to rewrite it and move resolves out to a resolve block on the state:

> Now, move all resolves out to a resolve block on the state:

Read here for more details and examples: [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#resolve-inside-views)